# SQL to return only previous full months

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table i have a date column called `APPDATE`, i would like to use this to restrict a query to return only the last 2 complete months.

For example, today is **28/03/17**, i would like the query to only return data from **February 2017** and **January 2017** and *not* to include any data from **March 2017**.

How would i do this please?

At the moment I've tried:

```
APPDATE > DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())
```

which includes March :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE APPDATE < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
      APPDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Assuming the current date is in March, then this logic would retain all records earlier than March 1 and greater than or equal to January 1.

Comment: Perfect, voted up. lbut less then 15 rep so wont show.